# fetch interaction from xConnect based on custom values

Tags: xdb, xconnect

I'm using sitecore 9.1.1

I'm trying to get interaction which having key "PlanMemberId" in CustomValues and value is "test123" against this key.

I'm able to get interaction based on WebVisit facet in below code.

how can I fetch interactions based on Custom Values which added explicitly while interaction added into xDB.

```
using (Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClient client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
            {
var result1 = client.Interactions.Where(x => x.WebVisit().SiteName == "website").WithExpandOptions(new InteractionExpandOptions(WebVisit.DefaultFacetKey)).GetBatchEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: Are you custom values in an interaction facet? Or literally the CustomValues. It looks like you need to convert your custom values to a custom facet for them to make it into xDB. https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/en/tracking-interaction-facets.html

Answer (score 1):

For CustomValues you need to convert them into a custom facet inside the convertToXConnectInteraction pipeline.

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/en/tracking-interaction-facets.html

Also: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/en/triggering-custom-events.html#UUID-9f9f7370-7ed1-79b5-d6a3-1416d7e4c6cf_N1560769852457

[image]

```
using Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Pipelines.ConvertToXConnectInteractionPipeline;
namespace Documentation
{
    public class ConvertInteractionFacet : ConvertToXConnectInteractionProcessorBase
    {
        public override void Process(ConvertToXConnectInteractionPipelineArgs args)
        {
            if (args != null)
            {
                var customValues = args.TrackerVisitData.CustomValues;

                var moodFacet = customValues[CustomerMood.DefaultFacetKey];

                if (moodFacet != null && moodFacet is CustomerMood)
                {
                    args.Facets.Add(CustomerMood.DefaultFacetKey, moodFacet);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
        <convertToXConnectInteraction>
            <processor patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Pipelines.ConvertToXConnectInteractionPipeline.ConvertToXConnectInteractionProcessor, Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect']" type="Documentation.ConvertInteractionFacet, Documentation"/>
        </convertToXConnectInteraction>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```